# Variable usage in html:textarea

Tags: java, textarea, struts

How to use variable in html:textarea?

e.g. 
Java code

```
package util;

public interface Literals {
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
}
```

my.jsp

```
<%@ page import="util.Literals" %>

<html:textarea rows="20" cols="100" property="buffer" value='
<%=Literals.LAST_NAME %>
${Literals.LAST_NAME}
#{Literals.LAST_NAME}
'>
</html:textarea>
```

I try to make "lastName" to appear at my.jsp but get the following instead:

```
<%=Literals.LAST_NAME %>
${Literals.LAST_NAME}
#{Literals.LAST_NAME}
```

Comment: Put the value *between* the textarea start/end tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
  <%@ page import="util.Literals" %>

  <bean:define id="fieldvalue" value='<%=
    Literals.LAST_NAME + "=Ma\n"
     + Literals.LAST_NAME + "=Smith"
    %>'/>
  <html:textarea rows="20" cols="100" property="buffer" value='${fieldvalue}
  '>
  </html:textarea>
```